# Docker is not able to translate service name to IP address internally

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, next.js, strapi

I am trying to containerize three images: my Next.js application, Strapi image and Mongo database.

I have a Dockerfile with instructions for my Next.js application:

```
FROM node:14.15.0

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
RUN npm run build
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

And I am assembling all images in my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.7"

services:

  mongo:
    container_name: example-mongo
    image: mongo:latest
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: ${DATABASE_NAME}
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'

  strapi:
    container_name: example-strapi
    image: strapi/strapi:latest
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - ./strapi-app:/usr/src/strapi-app
    ports:
      - '1337:1337'
  
  app:
    container_name: example-app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - mongo
      - strapi
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'

volumes:
  data:
  strapi-app:
```

My .env file looks like this:

```
DATABASE_CLIENT=mongo
DATABASE_HOST=mongo
DATABASE_PORT=27017
DATABASE_NAME=example
```

The issue is, that when my Next.js application is running the `npm run build`, it fails when trying to connect to the Mongo Database (connection string that it fails on: `mongodb://mongo:27017/example`). The error is `MongooseServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongo`.

From what I found around forums and in some threads, this usually points to some Docker internal DNS issues. It is not able to translate mongo to the IP address of the Mongo DB service.

I tried running just the strapi image with the Mongo DB, at it is able to connect to the Mongo DB without a hiccup. Am I missing some config for my Next.js application? Here is a bare bones example, that replicates the issue, for anyone interested: https://gitlab.com/jan.kraus.cf/next-mongo-strapi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting that error during the *build* stage of your environment. This runs before any containers have started, so of course the `mongo` service isn't available.

You can reproduce this by simply running `docker build .` in the directory containing your Dockerfile. It gets as far as:

```
Step 7/8 : RUN npm run build
 ---> Running in 28aa6347395f

> learn-starter@0.1.0 build /usr/src/app
> next build
```

And fails soon after that with:

```
info  - Collecting page data...
Trying to connect to MongoDB on: mongodb://mongo:27017/example
MongooseServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongo
[...]
```

Your build can't have dependencies on external databases or other resources. Anything like that needs to happen at *run* time rather than *build* time.

Comment: Oh right. That means I cannot use Next.js Static Site Generation and rather use Server Side. Rendering or Client Side Rendering.
 Is there a way to postpone the build face of a docker service, until another service is up and running?

Comment: You can probably use Next.js; you just need to arrange for it to run at container startup (e.g., via an `ENTRYPOINT` script or as part of your `CMD` script) instead of at build time. You would probably also need to account for the situation in which your app  container starts  up before MongoDB is ready to handle requests.